# Loop must iterate over collection: mw2__Tax_Code__c is a new error that I kept getting with the method below. Any suggestions would be great

Tags: apex

```java
public void getTaxCodeTriggerByIndex(Tax_Code__c taxCodes) {
    for (Tax_Code__c taxCode : taxCodes) {
        String taxCode2 =
        taxCode.Tax_Code__c +
        taxCode.Tax_Code_Prefix__c +
        taxCode.Tax_Code_Letter__c +
        taxCode.Tax_Code_Number__c;

        taxCode.Tax_Code_2__c = taxCode2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Loops only work on sets and lists, so you can't loop over an instance of an SObject. If your method signature was instead `public void getTaxCodeTriggerByIndex(List<Tax_Code__c> taxCodes) {`, then that would work (but you would also need to update the code that calls this method. Beyond that, you haven't provided enough details for people to provide more (or more specific) help. Remember, we're not mind-readers here. We can only possibly know whatever you put in any given question (even asking people to look through your previous question(s) is a bridge too far).

Comment: If you haven't done so already, going through the [Platform Developer Beginner](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/force_com_dev_beginner) and/or the [Build Apex Coding Skills](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/build-apex-coding-skills) trails on Trailhead is going to be helpful. Most of the material on the internet at large involving Apex assumes some level of familiarity with Object-Oriented programming, so if you don't have a good foundation there you're gonna find yourself running into a lot of issues with basic things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one `Tax_Code__c` so you are not looping over anything. You just need to get rid of the loop:

```
public void getTaxCodeTriggerByIndex(Tax_Code__c taxCode) {
    String taxCode2 =
    taxCode.Tax_Code__c +
    taxCode.Tax_Code_Prefix__c +
    taxCode.Tax_Code_Letter__c +
    taxCode.Tax_Code_Number__c;

    taxCode.Tax_Code_2__c = taxCode2;
}
```

If you want to loop over many Tax Codes, then you will need to change your method signature and define your argument as a list instead:

```
public void getTaxCodeTriggerByIndex(List<Tax_Code__c> taxCodes) {
    for (Tax_Code__c taxCode : taxCodes) {
        String taxCode2 =
        taxCode.Tax_Code__c +
        taxCode.Tax_Code_Prefix__c +
        taxCode.Tax_Code_Letter__c +
        taxCode.Tax_Code_Number__c;

        taxCode.Tax_Code_2__c = taxCode2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, greattt thanks

Comment: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getTaxCodeTriggerByIndex() from the type mw2.TaxCodeService is the current response that i get from this method, but it is the correct string for the method. What could the reasoning be?

Comment: Post a new question with the full code and we can answer fully. Usually that error is when you call a method but don't pass it any arguments or pass it the wrong arguments

Comment: just posted it in more detail for you